# How can I place ::before's background color before the parent's background color?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a react search bar component which has a white background, and I want to create a grey background on it, however, the grey background is supposed to be placed before the search bar, but the grey overlaps the white but does not overlap the text fields.

Here is the relevant css

```
.searchbar-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 4vw;
  left: 20vw;
  top: calc(50vh - 2vw);
  border-radius: 2vw;
  z-index: 3;
}

#searchbar-container-top::before {
  content: "";
  width: 60vw;
  height: 4vw;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

And the searchbar itself:

```
import React from "react";
import "./SearchBar.css";

export default class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.mouseDown = this.mouseDown.bind(this);
    this.mouseUp = this.mouseUp.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.redirect = this.redirect.bind(this);
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      magnifyingGlassImage: "magnifyingGlass.png",
      query: ""
    };
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // Add background wrapping div to searchbar.
    if (this.props.top === "true") {
      let lastScrollPosition = 0;
      let isRunning = false;

      function adjustHeight(scrollPosition) {
        const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        const isPhone = window.innerHeight / windowWidth >= 1;
        let heightToSetFixed, searchBarFixedInitialPosition;

        if (isPhone) {
          heightToSetFixed = 0.09 * windowWidth;
          searchBarFixedInitialPosition = -0.06 * windowWidth;
        } else {
          heightToSetFixed = 0.06 * windowWidth;
          searchBarFixedInitialPosition = -0.04 * windowWidth;
        };

        const searchBarContainer = document.querySelector(".searchbar-container");

        if (scrollPosition > heightToSetFixed) {
          const searchBarTopPosition = `${Math.min(searchBarFixedInitialPosition + (scrollPosition - heightToSetFixed), 0)}px`;

          searchBarContainer.style.position = "fixed";
          searchBarContainer.style.top = searchBarTopPosition;
        } else {
          searchBarContainer.style.position = "absolute";
          searchBarContainer.style.top = "0";
        };
      };

      adjustHeight(lastScrollPosition);

      document.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
        lastScrollPosition = window.scrollY;

        if (!isRunning) {
          window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
            adjustHeight(lastScrollPosition);
            isRunning = false;
          });
          
          isRunning = true;
        };
      });
    };
  };

  mouseDown() {
    this.setState({
      magnifyingGlassImage: "blueMagnifyingGlass.png"
    });
  };

  mouseUp() {
    this.setState({
      magnifyingGlassImage: "magnifyingGlass.png"
    });
  };

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      query: e.target.value
    });
  };

  redirect() {
    if (!this.state.query.length) return;
    
    let isQueryBlank = true;

    for (let item of this.state.query) {
      if (item !== " ") {
        isQueryBlank = false
        break;
      };
    };

    if (isQueryBlank) return;

    window.location.href = `search?type=text&query=${this.state.query}&page=1`
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div 
        className="searchbar-container" 
        id={this.props.top === "true" ? "searchbar-container-top" : ""}
      >
        <img 
          className="magnifying-glass"
          onMouseDown={this.mouseDown}
          onMouseUp={this.mouseUp}
          onClick={this.redirect}
          alt="Magnifying Glass"
          src={this.state.magnifyingGlassImage}
        />
        <input
          className="search-input"
          type="text"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder="Search Bong"
          value={this.state.query}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };
};
```

I thought before should always have a z-index less than the parent, so I tried setting the z-index to 2, to be less than 3 of the search bar but that did not work. Is there any way I can place the background of a ::before pseudoelement behind the parent?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the `div` will get the id `searchbar-container-top` (since that's how you use ::before)?

Comment: @Rojo Yes, the id is toggled depending on the prop. And I am experiencing this problem on the prop where the id is used.

Comment: Try adding `z-ndex: -1` to `::before`

Comment: @Rojo I already said in my question that I tried changing the z-index.

Comment: Yes but that was to `2`. `-1` has different effects.

Comment: @Rojo I tried that as you insist and it did not work.

Comment: What is the styling on searchbar-container-top?